# hypothesis testing using t-distribution

Tags: statistics

I am tutoring someone and we got to a problem that I haven't done in ages, and on top of that, a problem related to a concept that I never fully mastered when I took the class.  It's on the topic of hypothesis testing.  Here are the details.

She needed to collect some data from a population.  She collected a sample of $n=41$.  She needs to test the claim that the mean is more than $15$ at an $\alpha = 0.05$ confidence level.  So we have:

$H_0 : \mu = 15$

$H_1 : \mu > 15$

This will be a one tail test (since $H_1$ is such as it is), thus the critical value corresponding to our $\alpha$ (extracted from the student t-distribution table) will be $1.684$ and we will proceed to find our test statistic which will be $t = -14.999$.  Then, since $-14.999 < 1.684$, we will fail to reject the null-hypothesis as our test statistic fails to land in the reject region.  Does that sound legit?

As a side question, in her notes there was something about comparing the $p$ value to $\alpha$ and coming to the same conclusion.  From my understanding, this is not necessary, correct??

Answer (score 2):

First, you are correct that this a one-sample, right-tailed
t test at the 5% level, based on $n = 41$ observations, and so 40 degrees of freedom. This gives the critical value 1.684, as you say.
And that does mean that you reject $H_0$ if the observed t statistic
$T > 1.684.$

The t statistic in this problem is $T = \frac{\bar X - 15}{S/\sqrt{41}},$
where $\bar X$ and $S$ are the sample mean and standard deviation, respectively.
You did not provide the values of $\bar X$ or $S,$ so I cannot check whether
$T = -14.999,$ as you say.  Obviously, this value is not possible unless
$\bar X < 15.$ And if the sample mean is $\bar X < 15,$ the question arises why you would
be testing against the alternative $H_a: \mu > 15.$ Obviously, a sample mean
less than 15 provides *no* evidence that the population mean is greater than 15. So you will not reject $H_0$ at *any* reasonable significance level.

This leads me to wonder if someone has computed the observed value of $T$
incorrectly or has misunderstood the assignment and collected
irrelevant or incorrect data.

The question to find the P-value for a t test is usually asked when the
student is expected to use statistical software. The P-value of a right-tailed
test is the probability under the density curve of the distribution
$\mathsf{T}(df=40)$ to the right of the observed value of $T.$ In your case
you are asking for $P(T > -14.999),$ where $T \sim \mathsf{T}(df=40).$
In R statistical software I get the P-value, which is essentially $1.$
(The probability $P(T \le -14.999) = 2.559454 \times 10^{-18}.$)

In general, one cannot reject a null hypothesis at level $\alpha = 0.05$ if
the P-value exceeds 0.05. Roughly speaking, one says that the null
hypothesis is rejected for small P-values. (There is another saying that
one questions the model, the legitimacy of the data, or the computations
when the P-value is large---above 95% or so. This seems to apply in
the situation you describe.)

If you can tell me some details of the experiment (what is being measured and why), the numerical values of $\bar X$ and
$S$, and why $H_0$ and $H_a$ are chosen as you say, then maybe I can be
more helpful. As it stands, I can answer specific technical questions (as
above), but can't make sense of the particular application described.